# Snap SVG: String to Element

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

In jQuery you can simply creating an element by providing a string, like so:

```
var newElement = $('<div></div>');
```

How can I do the same thing in Snap SVG? I have a string like

```
<rect x="100" y="100" transform="matrix(-0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 -0.7071 1825.4047 1024.3746)" fill="#7EC242" width="230.02" height="56.723" stroke="#64bc46"/>
```

And I need an Element I can append to an already existing Snap document. I tried fragments, but they don't have all functions I need to manipulate the element afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do it with `parse` (I removed the transform so the code could work in the small SO snippet window):

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
var string = '<rect x="100" y="100" fill="#7EC242" width="230.02" height="56.723" stroke="#64bc46"/>'
var rect = Snap.parse(string);
s.append(rect);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="200">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the resulting object is a Fragment, which doesn't support operations like attr() or appendTo(). The function I am writing is part of a larger app and it needs to return the same type of object you get when calling "paper.circle(10, 10, 10)" for example. I assume the Snap Element is just a wrapper, so it should be possible to transform a Fragment into a Snap element though. I just couldn't find information about that anywhere

Comment: You can edit the resulting object, you just need to select it. You can't use the 'rect' var to change attributes, but you can select the rectangle object after you add it to the graph and then edit it. Here's one possibility:

    s.selectAll("[fill='#7EC242']").attr({fill:'red'})

Comment: or maybe better for your use case, just assign it to something and then do whatever you like: var rect=s.selectAll("[fill='#7EC242']")

Comment: .parse() returns a Fragment-Object. You can't use things like .attr() on a fragment. Any ideas to get a Element-Object from a sting?